# Data extract 'Delete file from ET FTP or Safehouse' not deleting file on enhancedFTP

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio

The Data Extract Type 'Delete file from ET FTP or Safehouse' is enabled in the account and I have created the Data Extract Activity.  However, when I am running the automaton, it is not deleting the file from the enhancedFTP. I am using Triggered Automation.

Filename: %%FILENAME_FROM_TRIGGER%%.csv.pgp

Am I missing anything in the setup?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use:
*%%FILENAME_FROM_TRIGGER%%.csv.pgp*

But use either:

*%%FILENAME_FROM_TRIGGER%%*

Or:

*%%FILENAME_FROM_TRIGGER_BASE%%.csv.pgp*

Reason why I think your deletion isn’t working is the fact that *FILENAME_FROM_TRIGGER* already holds the suffix, hence your activity is looking for filename.csv.pgp.csv.pgp - having suffixes added twice. You can see the full list of these different strings and examples on how to use them [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_substitution_strings_example.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will check that. But the strange thing is it is not throwing error like file not found etc..

Comment: @Rishikesh - did you have chance to check my suggested solution?

Comment: Hello Lukas, No, it not deleting the file on enhancedFTP. The steps complete successfully however did not delete the file. What could be other reasons?